# creating dictionary inside a dictionary for converting it into Json data

Tags: python, json

My workflow is, I'll be having some dictionaries in different files, I'll be calling them into a file, let's say demo.py. I have a variable temp_dict in demo.py, in which the dictionary from different files will get appended one by one.
Example ::::

```
    {
        "Action": None,
        "Parameter": "abc",
        "ParameterDescription": "def",
        "ExpectedValue": "ghi",
         {
            "Extensions":"jkl",
            "MappedData": "no",
            "Parameters": "pqr",
            "Labels": "Stu",
         }    
         {  
            "Recorder": "abc",
            "Diagnostics": "efg",
            "AdditionalRemarks": ""
         }

    }
```

I want this type of structure, I need to append dictionaries inside a dictionary, how can I do that.

I will also provide the python code

```
    # function to add data to JSON
    def write_json(new_data, filename='report.JSON'):
        # new_data is the dictioanries coming from other files, it will be converted into json and dump it into a file.
        
       with open(filename, 'w') as f:
           json_string=json.dumps(new_data)
           f.write(json_string)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to append them as values, but you need some key. you could set some mock key and the value will be a list that you will append the dict

Comment: It's is not valid json. You can't add value without key.

Comment: You can skip this all if you use `json.dump(new_data, f)`

Answer (score 1):

The data you've provided is not a valid python dictionary, nor valid JSON.

Dictionaries and JSON are `key: value` pairs. The value might be a nested dict/JSON, however in your example the nested dictionaries do not have a key.

However, something like this would work:

```
{
  "Action": None,
  "Parameter": "abc",
  "ParameterDescription": "def",
  "ExpectedValue": "ghi",
  "YOU NEED SOME NAME HERE": {
    "Extensions":"jkl",
    "MappedData": "no",
    "Parameters": "pqr",
    "Labels": "Stu",
  },
  …
}
```

You might have been thinking of json objects/dicts inside arrays. There the dictionaries don't have to be named, but that's because they implicitly have a name - their index (position) in the **ordered** array

```
[
  {
    "name": "Faboor",
    "type": "user"
  },
  {
    "name": "prithvi"
    "reputation": 19
  }
]
```